# Place multiple pics upon each other in a table cell

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to place multiple pictures upon each other in a table - unfortunately not successfully. The final result will be a table with different bowling-pin-combinations as they kept standing after the first ball. So depending on the bowling result I will create the picture by laying the appropriate pin-images upon each other.

For the test I just try to lay a circle upon a rectangle:

[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wScV3.png)

[That's what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Vxz.png)

That's my code, tried all combinations of absolute & relative positions...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>IMG overlapping</title>


</head>
<body>

<table border='2'>

<tr><th>Pins after 1st Ball</th><th>Blabla</th></tr>

<tr><td>
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
<img style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;" width='10%' src = './r.png'/>
<img style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;" width='10%' src = './k.png'/>
</div>
</td><td>Bla1</td></tr>

</table>


</body>
</html>
```

It would be great, if somebody could help me :)

Thank you!

PS: Here are the two images:
[k.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMdTP.png)
[r.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PgTp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place one image above another, one of them has to have an absolute position. You only need minimal changes to your code to make it happen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>IMG overlapping</title>


</head>
<body>

<table border="2">

    <tr>
        <th>Pins after 1st Ball</th>
        <th>Blabla</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
                <img width="10%" src="./r.png"/>
                <img style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" width="10%" src="./k.png"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>Bla1</td>
    </tr>

</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Please, consider learning the following:

- do not use tables to handle layout,
- do not use inline CSS, use external files instead.

Comment: Thank you yery much! It is working perfectly.